# SemVer collision: How to release bug fix over the last stable version if there are some alpha/beta/rc versions and the work is in progress?

Tags: npm, versioning, package.json, beta, semantic-versioning

I'm maintaining [some js library](https://github.com/dhilt/ngx-ui-scroll/). Releases follow SemVer. Current stable version is **1.5.0**. I'm working on **1.5.1** and have **1.5.1-beta.2** which is published at npm with "next" tag. Today I got bug report, discovered the issue and ready to fix it. The thing is that **1.5.1** is not going to be finished during nearest days, it turned out to be more complicated than I planned initially. But I want the fix to be published.

What is the right strategy in this situation? Obvious approach which I'd like to avoid is to postpone the bug fix until **1.5.1** is done and published and then release **1.5.2** containing the fix.

Another way is to publish the fix as **1.5.1** based on **1.5.0** and then continue previous work switching it from **1.5.1-beta.2** to **1.5.2** or even **1.6.0**. I'm concerning about inconsistency with the result chain in this case:

1.5.0 → 1.5.1-beta → 1.5.1-beta.1 → 1.5.1-beta.2 → 1.5.1 (bug fix, based on 1.5.0) → 1.5.2 (based on 1.5.1-beta.2)

How such collisions are being addressed using SemVer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so you have bug set A currently baking as 1.5.1-beta2 and you have a new bug set B that you want to get the fix out for immediately.  The correct mechanism for this is to fork 1.5.0, fix bug set B, and release 1.5.2 (assuming you don't need a beta).  Then merge your B fixes into your A working branch and release 1.5.3-beta1 and proceed to drive that to an official release.

It gets a little more complicated when you have two parallel beta sequences running, particularly when you're not sure which is going to make it to release first, but it is manageable.  The key is to to just keep in mind, how SemVer precedence impacts the decisions your customers make (the algorithms they apply), whether to fast-track a particular version into their production systems, verses how their developers pull bits from you.

My production systems, have two inputs:

1. Development is the product of my engineers.
2. Automated maintenance is the product of a system that:

   - Pulls patch releases and applies them to a fork of my current production code.
   - Tests the applied changes against an extensive suite of functional and performance tests.
   - If the tests are green, flight tests the changes in my production environment, while monitoring for unusual changes in production failure rates.
   - As long as everything is going well and a human doesn't step-in to stop it, eventually rolls out the changes to the entire production system.

There are of course, variations for services and packaged products.  The point is, you can use your release points to signal to your customers automation, or developers, that you have an important bug fix that has little risk of breaking anything.  There is no requirement that 1.5.2 have any lineage back to 1.5.1-beta#.  You are not required to ever release a 1.5.1.  It is customary however to add a comment in your release notes that 1.5.2 is a hot fix for the bug in 1.5.0 and does not contain the fixes in 1.5.1-beta#.

While you may never encounter a need to do so, you don't have to include the bug fixes from 1.5.2 in your eventual 1.5.3 release, provided the later release, passes your quality controls.  It is sometimes the case that a specific bug fix, winds up not being applicable in later releases.

How you maintain your product quality is entirely up to you.  How you signal the level of risk/importance for a specific release, is defined by the [SemVer](https://semver.org) standard.

Comment: "You are not required to ever release a 1.5.1"  Unfortunately, I already forced myself to complete "beta" changes before the release of a new bug fix, which caused some stress. But next time I will feel myself more freely.