# how to release a minor version of npmjs package from an old version

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning

I have a private package in `npm` which is very frequently updated, 
and i want to do a `minor change` on one of the`previous versions`of the package.

for example my current version is 1.14.0 and i want to make change on top of 1.11.1, so that all the changes after 1.11.1 are excluded.

**EDIT**

versions released in between

1.11.1, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.12.2, 1.13.0, 1.14.0

Is it possible? if yes how? 
Thanks

Comment: It might be useful if you edited your question to show/list all the versions that have been released between `1.11.1` and your current version `1.14.0` - this would help provide further context. However, what's certain is that if you make a change to `1.11.1` it can't be released again as `1.11.1` because as [point #3](https://semver.org/#spec-item-3) in the Semver guidelines state:  _"Once a versioned package has been released, the contents of that version MUST NOT be modified. Any modifications MUST be released as a new version."_

Comment: I have updated the details

Comment: it is possible for me to make a new version on top of the old one, something like 1.11.2

Comment: You say; _"I want to do a **minor** change"_, so I assume the change(s) you want to make to `1.11.1` result in a [MINOR](https://semver.org/#summary) change in Semver terms, i.e. they _"add functionality in a backwards compatible manner"_, however you've already released `1.12.0` - so you can't do that. If however the changes you want to make are actually a `PATCH` in Semver terms, i.e. they _"make backwards compatible bug fixes"_, then you can release it as `1.11.2`. Note, when you publish `1.11.2` to the registry it gets auto tagged _"latest"_, so you'll need to use the ...

Comment: ... [dist-tag](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag) command to remove the _"latest"_ distribution tag from `1.11.2` and reassign it to `1.14.0`. Also be mindful that any consumers of your package who have `^1.11.1` specified in their _package.json_ (note the default caret `^` that npm applies) they'll not get `1.11.2`, and instead they'll get `1.14.0`. Only if consumers have `~1.11.1` (note the tilde `~`) specified in their _package.json_ will they get `1.11.2`.

Comment: Seems that @RobC has already covered the NPM nuances for you.  You might also want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60859070/3150445) that I gave to a similar recent question.

Comment: You're effectively branching your product.  Have you considered a product name change?  Something like PNameClassic.  Are you planning on merging your new changes down stream of 1.14.x somewhere?

Comment: as mentioned by @RobC i made the changes on top of last commit for 1.11.1 and form that i released 1.11.2 and that works fine as per my requirement, as these changes are not required in the 1.14.0+, this is good enough.

Comment: @jwdonahue this is a good post, thanks for the reference